# initializing 2 random variables using the same Random a = new Random

Tags: java, variables, random

I am writing a script using 'java.util.Random' and I am trying to initialize two random variables for the same println but it only works if I comment out one of the variables. Here is the code where my problem is:

```
Random a = new Random();
    date = a.nextInt(29) + 1;
    year = a.nextInt(2019 - 2044)+ 1;

    System.out.println("The best day of your life will be on " + month + " " + date + ","+ " " + year + ".....give or take.\n");
```

I can't figure out how to initialize and use BOTH variables 'date' and 'year' at the same time, which is where I think the problem is. Since when I comment out one variable the other will work fine Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Class specification says `bound` in `nextInt(bound)` must be positive, otherwise it throws exception, and `(2019 - 2044)` isn't positive. Maybe that is the problem? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: I t actually was kind of the problem. I am going to post how I did it now.

Answer (score 1):

So I thought the problem was initializing both variables at once but it was actually the second variable that was the problem. What I wanted was a random number between: 2020 and 2045. I was using the wrong formula for this. What I ended up doing instead is:

```
Random a = new Random();
date = a.nextInt(29) + 1;
YEAR = a.nextInt((2044) - 2018 + 1) + 2018;
```

Where the second variable shows the way to get a random number within a set range.

EX. variable = a.nextInt((max) - min + 1) + min

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to not - prefer `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` to `new Random()`, it is faster and can do more. Also, `a` is a very bad name for a variable, how about `rng` or `random`.

Comment: Also, `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`, unlike `Random`, has a `nextInt` method that takes `min` and `max` bound. So you could simplify your code to `ThreadLocalRandom rng = ThreadLocalRandom.next();` and then `date = rng.nextInt(1, 30)` and `YEAR = rng.nextInt(2018, 2045)`.

Comment: And `YEAR` does not follow Java naming conventions. CAPSLOCK is only used for constants (`static final`), which this variable isnt.